# In SQL Server, how to move/import a multiple .trc files to a trace table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, trace, sql-server-profiler

I have a set of rollover .trc files recorded with Sql Profiler.

```
mytrace.trc

mytrace_1.trc

mytrace_2.trc

mytrace_3.trc
```

I can import the first one using this command:

```
use [my-database]
SELECT * INTO trace_folder
FROM::fn_trace_gettable('C:\mytrace.trc', 4)
```

However, this only appears to load the first file, not all four.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You'll want to use fn_trace_gettable:

From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188425.aspx:

```
USE AdventureWorks;
GO
SELECT * INTO temp_trc
FROM fn_trace_gettable('c:\temp\mytrace.trc', default);
GO
```

Also, a warning from the documentation:

> Be aware that the fn_trace_gettable function will not load rollover
>   files (when this option is specified by using the number_files
>   argument) where the original trace file name ends with an underscore
>   and a numeric value. (This does not apply to the underscore and number
>   that are automatically appended when a file rolls over.) As a
>   workaround, you can rename the trace files to remove the underscores
>   in the original file name. For example, if the original file is named
>   Trace_Oct_5.trc and the rollover file is named Trace_Oct_5_1.trc, you
>   can rename the files to TraceOct5.trc and TraceOct5_1.trc.

Comment: updated my question for clarity -- I am interested in multiple rollover .trc files

Comment: Passing "default" as the second parameter should load all trace files sequentially, unless the initial tracefile name ends with an underscore and a number (which in your example, it does not).

Not sure why you are not getting them all loaded. Are they all in the same folder?

Comment: ah, that was the issue. (my original files were actually named mytrace_20100420.trc etc...) Thanks!

Comment: @frankadelic, how did you get it to work?  I've got the same situation, but when I try to load up my file, i goet "file <filename> deither does not exist or is not a recognizable trace file".  I know the file is there, but for some reason it can't load it.

Comment: @russds - It would seem that the "..is not a recognizable trace file" may be pertinent here. Anyways, think the community would suggest putting this in a seperate question, as it is not directly related to the question above.

Comment: @PaulKearney-pk I think it would be worth noting the "underscore and a number" limitation directly in the answer.

Comment: Yes, definitely put a note about _ in file names, I stumbled on it too.

Answer (score 1):

From SQL 2008 BOL ms-help://MS.SQLCC.v10/MS.SQLSVR.v10.en/s10de_6tsql/html/c2590159-6ec5-4510-81ab-e935cc4216cd.htm

Be aware that the fn_trace_gettable function will not load rollover files (when this option is specified by using the number_files argument) where the original trace file name ends with an underscore and a numeric value. (This does not apply to the underscore and number that are automatically appended when a file rolls over.) As a workaround, you can rename the trace files to remove the underscores in the original file name. For example, if the original file is named Trace_Oct_5.trc and the rollover file is named Trace_Oct_5_1.trc, you can rename the files to TraceOct5.trc and TraceOct5_1.trc.

This was the problem I had.  My Server Side Trace names are _*Purpose.trc.  What was I thinking when I embedded "*" in teh file name :)